# Is there a way to recalculate all sheets of active workbook?

Tags: excel

[microsoft explains](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-formula-recalculation-iteration-or-precision-73fc7dac-91cf-4d36-86e8-67124f6bcce4) in Excel we can use F9, Shift+F9, Ctrl+Alt+F9, or Ctrl+Shift+Alt+F9:

**F9**: Recalculate formulas that have changed since the last calculation, and formulas dependent on them, in **all open workbooks**. If a workbook is set for automatic recalculation, you do not need to press F9 for recalculation.

**Shift+F9**: Recalculate formulas that have changed since the last calculation, and formulas dependent on them, in the **active worksheet**.

**Ctrl+Alt+F9**: Recalculate all formulas in **all open workbooks**, regardless of whether they have changed since the last recalculation.

**Ctrl+Shift+Alt+F9**: Check dependent formulas, and then recalculate all formulas in **all open workbooks**, regardless of whether they have changed since the last recalculation.

But is there a way to recalculate **all worksheets of active workbook**?

Comment: I don't see a way without a VBA Macro. There is a "Recalculate workbook before saving" checkbox in the Excel Formulas Options

Comment: i disabled "Recalculate workbook before saving" due to complexity of the computation...

Comment: as a side note, besides the obvious close all other workbooks, there are ways to open the workbook in a separate Excel Application instance. My guess is that it's not the "complexity of the computation", but the use of a lot of inefficient volatile or array formulas

Comment: open workbook in a separate excel application is a nice idea, thanks!